# Can't log in to Google account

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, google-account

I am trying to log in with my Google account but I can't, it says : "Can't establish conection to server. This could be a temporary problem or your phone may not be provishioned for data services". I really don't know what to do, I may have deleted some stuff with titanium backup but I can't reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing data from Google Play Services and all Google apps and deleting your Google account from your phone. Then reboot and try logging back in.